# How do I add pyqt6 documentation to Kdevelop

Tags: kdevelop

I would like to use Kdevelop to develop some pyqt6 apps kdevelop has code completion for pyqt5 I believe but I would like to add pyqt6 there is a feature to add documentation for new modules in kdevelop but I'm not sure how to do this as the documentation (no pun intended) is non existent as to how to do that.